# What would someone who is prejudiced against a country be called?

Tags: single-word-requests, racism

The reason why I asked was because I saw a movie and that question came up in my mind.

*Racist* doesn't seem to be the right word, as country doesn't necessarily imply race.

An example of how it might be used would be:

> This movie was about a group of ______ who victimised immigrants from
>   the neighbouring country.

Comment: "Bigot" is probably the simplest term.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange prefers thoughtful, well-researched questions; in order to answer properly, we would want to know the context you would use the word or phrase in, and what terms you might have considered already. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as well as the special guidance on [tag:single-word-requests].

Comment: Lizzie, I think this is a great question (enough to prompt me to research an answer!), but it needed more detail to meet our EL&U site standards. I've made some edits including adding an example sentence. If you don't like what I've added, you can [edit] the question yourself. I can think of plenty of examples where the discrimination is based on country rather than race (e.g. [Anglophobia in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglophobia#Australia_and_New_Zealand) has led to action on the use of "Pom") and I myself have wondered what the word for this is. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** There's no specific word for people who vilify or are prejudiced against other "countries". The closest general term would be **bigot**, but there are also terms for prejudice against certain specific nations/nationalities or ethnicities.

---

It's important to use the correct terms. Firstly, the term you're looking for is **not** "racist", since this can only be used in relation to *race* rather than nationality, ethnicity or "country".

[Merriam-Webster defines *racism* as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racism):

> 1: a belief that race is the primary determinant of human traits and
>   capacities and that racial differences produce an inherent superiority
>   of a particular race
>   2a: a doctrine or political program based on
>   the assumption of racism and designed to execute its principles
>   2b: a
>   political or social system founded on racism
>   3: racial prejudice or discrimination

[Interestingly, *racism* is a relatively recent term. Merriam-Webster cites its first known use as 1902. That's not to say the concept or the practice didn't exist before then; M-W's dictionary entry includes two full paragraphs on "The History and Dictionary Meaning of Racism", and is worth reading].

---

So, is there a specific word for people who vilify, or are prejudiced against, other "countries"? The answer is no. In the absence of a specific word, the most applicable general term would be:

> [**bigot**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot)
>
> > a person who is obstinately or intolerantly devoted to his or her
> >     own opinions and prejudices
> >
> > *especially*: one who regards or treats
> >     the members of a group (such as a racial or ethnic group) with hatred
> >     and intolerance
>
> [Merriam-Webster]

*Bigot* significantly pre-dates *racist*: M-W says the first known use was in 1660.

---

The term *bigot* shouldn't be confused with ***xenophobe***, though no doubt there are parallels between the two. [Merriam-Webster defines *xenophobe* as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophobe):

> one unduly fearful of what is foreign and especially of people of
>   foreign origin

M-W also offers the following broader background and explanation:

> *Xenophobe* is partly based on the Greek noun *xenos*, meaning "stranger,
>   guest, foreigner". Unlike other phobias, *xenophobia* isn't really
>   considered an abnormal condition; instead, it's generally thought of
>   as just serious narrow-mindedness, the kind of thinking that goes
>   along with racism and extreme patriotism. In times of war, a
>   government will often actually try to turn all its citizens into
>   xenophobes.

---

Lastly, there are many words that define a fear, aversion or hatred of a *specific* nationality, ethnicity or cultural identity. These words are most easily formed with the either the prefix *anti-* (e.g. *anti-American*, *anti-Semite*) or the suffix *-phobe* (e.g. *Anglophobe*, *Francophobe*, *Islamophobe*). Wikipedia provides a comprehensive [list of anti-cultural, anti-national, and anti-ethnic terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anti-cultural,_anti-national,_and_anti-ethnic_terms).

Answer (score 2):

xenophobic or xenophobia. there are country-specific words, such as anglophobic or francophobic.

Comment: A *xenophobe* is afraid of "the different," and I would expect a xenophobe to hate all unfamiliar groups, not merely one specific country. If you hate China and only China, treating all other countries favorably or with indifference, I'd call you a sinophobe but not a xenophobe.

Answer (score 2):

While this is more commonly used to refer to
*preference* to / prejudice *in favor of* a country
(typically one's own country),
and prejudice against ***all*** other nations,
***nationalist*** seems to work:

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nationalist):
>
>   A person who strongly identifies with their own nation
>     and vigorously supports its interests,
>     especially to the exclusion or detriment of the interests of other nations.
>   *‘he was a staunch nationalist during his 22 years in power’*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nationalist):
>
>   [adjective]
>   Nationalist means connected with a person's great love for their nation. 
>     It is often associated with the belief that their nation is better
>     than any other nation, and in this case is often used showing disapproval.
>   *Political life has been infected by growing nationalist sentiment.*
>
> [noun]
>   A nationalist is someone with nationalist views.
>   *...the small band of nationalists
>   who reject imported American culture and Western-style politics.*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/nationalist_1):
>
>   someone who feels that their nation’s interests
>     should be considered as more important than those of other nations
>   *The right-wing nationalists won 43 seats.*
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nationalist?q=nationalist_1):
>
>   a person who strongly believes their country is better than others:
>   *violent protests by nationalists*

Most of the above are secondary definitions; primary definitions include:

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nationalist):
>
>   A person who advocates or supports the political independence
>     of a particular nation or people.
>   *‘a Basque nationalist’*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nationalist):
>
>   [adjective]
>   Nationalist means connected with
>     the desire of a group of people within a country
>     for political independence.
>   *The crisis has set off a wave of nationalist feelings in Quebec.*
>
> [noun]
>   A nationalist is someone with nationalist views.
>   *...demands by nationalists for an independent state.*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/nationalist_1):
>
>   someone who believes that their group, state, or nation
>     should be independent
>   *Serb/Kazakh/Zulu nationalists*
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nationalist?q=nationalist_1):
>
>   a person who wants their country to be politically independent

IMO, the word ***nationalist*** could be used
in the sample sentence in the question,
and it would be understood with the desired meaning.

Answer (score 1):

nativist:

> Nativism is the political policy of promoting the interests of native inhabitants against those of immigrants,[1] including by supporting immigration-restriction measures.[2]
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nativism_(politics)