# What is the word for discrimination based on nationality?

Tags: single-word-requests

Discrimination based on race is racism, discrimination based on sex is sexism. However, discrimination based on nationality is not nationalism because nationalism is pride for your country.

Here are some examples of discrimination based on nationality:

Ex. 1: You won't befriend a British man because their country used to have control over your country.

Ex. 2: You charge higher life insurance rates for an American man solely because they are American; you think they're all obese gun carriers.

Ex. 3: You want to work with a Chinese man because you think Chinese people are smart.

So, what would the word for discrimination based on nationality or country origin be?

Comment: Usually we call that *racism*.  Virtually no one knows specifically what they mean when they say "race" - it's a word that's based on 18th century ideas that almost no one believes in anymore.  Here's an example from the *Journal of Black Studies* using "racism" to describe the Rwandan genocide: ["Scourge of Racism: Genocide in Rwanda"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40282573)

Comment: what do you mean by "18th century ideas that almost no one believe in anymore"? Do you mean the idea that race is the color of your skin, or that some races are inferior?

Comment: I'm talking about the "scientific" concept of race, popularized in the 18th century, that held that there is some small number of discrete groups, e.g. Caucasoid, Mongoloid, Negroid, American Indian, and Malayan, and that members of these groups share important physical and mental qualities.  What I really meant is that if you pressed someone to define "race" they couldn't do it, because we're pretty sure those ideas about the 5 races and their essential qualities are wrong, but we don't know what's right. And yet we keep using the word.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/476907/191178 but I don’t think that question should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would someone who is prejudiced against a country be called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476907/what-would-someone-who-is-prejudiced-against-a-country-be-called)